# ASP.NET Core Docker port forwarding on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: asp.net, networking, docker, asp.net-core, portforwarding

I cannot reach ASP.NET Core app running on Docker form host.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000
EXPOSE 5000
```

I run it like this: `docker run -v $(pwd):/app -p 5000:5000 -it dotnet` from application's directory. Then I execute `dotnet run` command inside the attached container and get the result of:

> Content root path: /app
>
> Now listening on: http://*:5000
>
> Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

I also tried running `dotnet run --server.urls=http://*:5000` directly passing attribbutes to Kestrel.

Unfortunately I'm not able to access server from the host by using localhost, host IP address nor the container's IP address.

```
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
11ec3be37816        dotnet              "/bin/bash"         17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes       0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   nostalgic_morse
```

There are some strange entries (I guess) like this:

```
$ netstat | grep 5000
tcp        0      0 mic22-Lenovo-Z50-:44824 172.17.0.2:5000         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:50914         localhost:5000          ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 localhost:5000          localhost:50914         ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: It does work, I have done -p 5000:5000 and then went to HTTP://localhost:5000 and it all worked for me. Are you sure the container is running and ports are mapped, and no other app is using the same port?

Comment: @JoelHarkes changing port to another one didn't help. I'm sure the container is running because it's started in the interactive mode.